# Conda returns "Solving environment: done" when creating a virtual environment, and it keeps getting stuck

Tags: conda, virtual, environment

all,

I am trying to install tensorflow recently, and frequently use conda to create and delete virtual environments. Now I have the problem mentioned in the title. At present, I have tried the following methods and none of the problems have been solved:

① Completely uninstall anaconda, delete the anaconda installation package in the root directory and the corresponding environment variables in ~/.bashrc.
②Execute "conda clearn --all"
③Replace the mirror source

After reinstalling conda, you can check the conda version normally, that is, there is no problem in my installation process.

So, what should I do now, I look forward to your answers, thank you in advance.

Comment: Add some `-v` flags (you can use it more than once) to the command to enable verbosity. This should let you more precisely identify if it really is "stuck" and where it happens.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. I changed the command for creating a virtual environment to the following: "conda create -n test -v", and returned "Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
"After that, it stuck for a long time.

Comment: Try multiple: `-vv` or `-vvv` for more verbosity.

Comment: Hello, my problem is solved. I backed up the data under the account and reopened an account. I have to admit that this is not a good way~